# How can I change text color of certain cells in UITableView?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview

So, I'm making an app in Xcode 6 (Swift 1). I'm trying to make certain cells' text colors green, and others' red, however, I'm not successful. Here's my code:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate,     UITableViewDataSource {
@IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
var items: [String] = ["green", "red"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.items.count;
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell:UITableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as UITableViewCell

    cell.textLabel?.text = self.items[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {
    println("You selected cell #\(indexPath.row)!")
}
}
```

And here's my code for changing the universal text color:

```
cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor greenColor];
```

So, for example, how can I make the "green" cell green, and the "red" cell red? Thanks!

Comment: Where are you changing the cell textLabel color?

Comment: After the "var items" declaration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After the `var items` declaration, add this:

```
let itemColors = [UIColor.greenColor(), UIColor.redColor()]
```

In `tableView(_:cellForRowAtIndexPath:)`, add this before the return statement:

```
cell.textLabel?.textColor = itemColors[indexPath.row]
```

Comment: Thanks! Two things, though. First, I get an error using the second line of code "UILabel?" does not have a member named "textColor". Second, I'm assuming I'll put the items that I want green in between the parentheses, right?

Comment: I've updated my answer. You put the colors of the items in the `itemColors` array.

Comment: I still get errors when putting the items in the  "let itemColors= [UIColor.greenColor(), UIColor.redColor()]" parentheses. I think I'm doing something wrong

Comment: "I still get errors" is not enough information. Edit your question to include your updated code and the errors. Copy and paste. Don't retype them.

Comment: Here are the two errors: 1.) Use of unresolved identifier 'green' 2.) 'ViewController' does not have a member named 'itemColors'

Comment: let itemColors... must be declared on the view controller itself. And rob is not using "green" in his example, but UIColor.greenColor(). Update your question to show where you get these errors